# How do I find the line number in which the function is ending in Ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Generally by using the `ctags -x <file_name.rb>` this command will give the line numbers in which each functions in that ruby file starts.

Example:

```
ctags -x /home/thillaiselvan/selva/Engg/CVS_Admin/CVS_TEST/src/application_helper.rb
```

Sample output:

```
select_user      method      604 /home/thillaiselvan/selva/Engg/CVS_Admin/CVS_TEST/src/application_helper.rb def select_user( name = 'user' , field = 'id' )
```

So from the output I can understand that in application_helper.rb file in line number 604 the `select_user` function is starting.

My requirement is, is there any way to find the line number in which each functions ends.
Please help.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*exuberant-ctags* and other ctags software I know of don't have this feature. You may want to implement it yourself in Ruby, by taking a Ruby tokenizer/parser, and finding the `end` corresponding to the `def` found in the line emitted by ctags.